# cannot unpack non-iterable float object

Tags: python, python-3.7

Whenever I run my code I keep getting the error of "cannot unpack non-iterable float object", I'm confused on where the error is coming from, do I have to use the iterating variable in some way?

```
def DEADBEEF(n):
    count = 0 
    for i in range(n):
        x ,y = np.random.uniform(0,1)
        if (np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)<=1):
            count = count + 1
     answer = count/100
     return answer

holder = DEADBEEF(100)
```

Comment: What do you expect to be the return value of `np.random.uniform(0, 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

[`np.random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) returns a single float as long as you don't pass the `size` parameter.

If you want to use `x, y = ...`, you must supply at least two values on the right side of the assignment.

If you want to assign a float to both `x` and `y` using `np.random.uniform`, try using the `size` parameter:

```py
x, y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=2)
```

Comment: Wow that was such a simple thing, that had me stuck for an hour. Thank you!